# Formato de fechas SQL

Tags: php, html, sql, date, entrada

Tengo creada la siguiente tabla en una base de datos **SQL**:

```
create table session(
     SessionId int auto_increment unique,
     SessionIni datetime,
     SessionFin datetime,
     UsHGTAG int,
     PcId int,
     primary key (SessionId)
);
```

¿Cómo hago para que **PHP** capture los datos de un formulario **HTML** en el formato `año/mes/dia hora` apropiado de manera que pueda guardarlo en la tabla `session` en los campos `sessionIni` y `SessionFin` y luego realizar cálculos de tiempo con ellos?

Ya el archivo **PHP** esta correctamente conectado al `index.html` y la base de datos.

El problema es que el formato de fecha que trae el input en **HTML** es de *dia/mes/año* ademas no incluye la hora por tratarse de un input `type:date`.

Comment: Puedes colocar la hora en un input tipo number, en php concatenas y usas la función strtotime...

Comment: ¿Podrías poner el HTML del formulario (me interesa, sobre todo, saber cómo es el `<input>` de fecha? ¿Usas algún widget como datepicker o similar?

Comment: ¿La respuesta respondió tu duda? ¿Tienes alguna duda más?

Comment: saludos OscarGarcia te comento estoy usando el típico <input type="date" name="fecha" />.... y no estoy usando ningun widget... probare tu respuesta ya que esta bastante completa y luego te comento

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aunque el valor mostrado por el navegador está basado en la configuración local de éste, en realidad [el dato que será enviado SIEMPRE estará codificado como `AAAA-MM-DD`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/input/date#Valor):

> Cabe destacar que el formato de fecha mostrado difiere del `value` en sí: el formato de fecha mostrado se escogerá en función de la configuración regional del navegador del usuario, aunque el `value` de fecha siempre se formatee como `aaaa-mm-dd`.

Es justo el que requiere MySQL para sus campos [`DATETIME`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-literals.html):

> MySQL reconoce valores `DATE` en los siguientes formatos:
>
> - Como cadena en formato `'AAAA-MM-DD'` o `'AA-MM-DD'`.
> - [...]
>
> MySQL reconoce valores `DATETIME` y `TIMESTAMP` en los siguientes formatos:
>
> - Como una cadena en formato `'AAAA-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'` o `'AA-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'`.
> - [...].

Si se introduce un valor `AAAA-MM-DD` en un campo de tipo `DATETIME` se producirá una conversión de tipo `DATE` a `DATETIME`, poniendo la hora, minutos y segundos a 0 (`AAAA-MM-DD 00:00:00`).

Puedes concatenar ambos valores en PHP para generar una cadena del último tipo:

```
<?php
$datetime = $_POST['fecha'] . ' ' . $_POST['hora'];
```

Aunque debes tener en cuenta que esa fecha estará en franja horaria local, por lo que tendrás que tenerlo en cuenta enviando la franja del usuario para almacenar las fechas en la base de datos en UTC siempre que te sea posible.

Aquí tienes un ejemplo práctico mostrando que el formato enviado será el correcto:

```js
function comprueba(form) {
  /* Calculamos la fecha en formato UTC. La sustitución
      de T por " " no es estrictamente necesaria */
  form.datetime.value = new Date(
    form.fecha.value + ' ' + form.hora.value
  ).toISOString().substr(0,19).replace('T', ' ');
  console.log('Fecha: ', form.fecha.value);
  console.log('Hora: ', form.hora.value);
  console.log('Datetime en UTC: ', form.datetime.value);
  return false;
}
window.onload = function() {
  /* Ponemos la fecha y hora actual */
  var fecha = new Date();
  document
    .querySelector('input[type="date"]')
    .value = fecha.toISOString().substr(0,10);
  document
    .querySelector('input[type="time"]')
    .value = fecha.toTimeString().substr(0, 5);
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return comprueba(this)">
  <input type="date" name="fecha" />
  <input type="time" name="hora" />
  <input type="hidden" name="datetime" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php date_default_timezone_set('America/Bogota'); $fecha = date('Y-m-d'); ?>
```

O completamente: `<?php 
                    date_default_timezone_set('America/Bogota');
                    $fecha = date('Y-m-d h:i:s ', time());
                ?>`

La variable "$fecha", la pones en el elemento que necesitas y ya tiene la fecha por defecto.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta!